# What is the difference between the and operator and or operator in a for loop?

Tags: c, loops, logical-operators

This loop is breaking with the (||) 'OR' operator but not with the (&&) 'AND' operator. Why is that? What's the difference between the two?

```
    int a;
    char ch;
    for(a=1;a<=20;a++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a);
        printf("do you want to break the loop(y/n)");
        scanf(" %c",&ch);
        if(ch=='y' && ch=='Y')
        {
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can a character be *both* "y" *and* "Y" at the same time? Can it be *either* "y" *or* "Y"?

Answer (score 5):

The statement

```
if (ch=='y' && ch=='Y')
{
    break;
}
```

says "if the character is simultaneously the character `y` and the character `Y`, then exit the loop." But that can't happen, since a character can't simultaneously be both `y` and `Y`.

On the other hand, the code

```
if (ch=='y' || ch=='Y')
{
    break;
}
```

says "if the character is either `y` or `Y`, then exit the loop." And it is indeed possible for a character to be one of `y` or `Y`, even if it can't be both.

Comment: @sensie Can you explain specifically what code you ran, what you saw when you ran it, and why it isn't what you expected?

Comment: but i am getting the expected output when i try `if(ch!='y' && ch!='Y')`  i am just a beginner and sorry for the dumb question

Comment: What inputs are you providing? What is the expected output?

Comment: my expectation output is to break the loop when typed 'n' and continue the loop when typed 'y'.

Comment: To confirm - you're sure you're running the version that uses `&&`? To confirm this, can you run that version of the code, but add a `printf` somewhere that says "I am running the `&&` version" so that you can confirm it's the right code?

Comment: @sensie "but i am getting the expected output" Ah, because the complex expression in your comment, is different than the one in your question and is the result of applying [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) upon the "other hand" statement in this answer.

Comment: @sensie Can you update the code in your question to exactly match the code you're running? Seems like they're different.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to know the difference between `&&` and  `||`

What is logical AND(&&) ?

When you use logical and i.e `&&` in between statements it will go through all those statements and check every statement in condition.

```
if ( ch == 'Y' && ch1 == 'y')
{
    // Here it check both the conditions
    // When both the conditions comes true then if block will execute.
 }
```

What is logical OR (||) ?

Logical OR ( || ) is something which try to find one possible condition which is true.
When you put multiple conditions using `||` then compiler doesn't go through all condition it will stop check the condition when it encounters a valid condition.

```
if ( ch == 'Y' || ch1 == 'y')
{
    // If you input any value
    // When any one condition from both comes true then 
    // Your if block will be executed
 }
```

As per your assumption you have to give two valid inputs to break the if statement

```
int a;
char ch;
char ch1;
for(a=1;a<=20;a++)
{
    printf("%d\n",a);
    printf("do you want to break the loop y/n : ");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);
    printf("\n Are you sure Y/N : ");
    scanf(" %c",&ch1);
    if(ch=='y' && ch1=='Y')
    {
        break;
    }

}
return 0;
```